# how can I make emacs use other css for orgmode publish

Tags: emacs, org-mode, publishing

When using orgmode in Emacs, when I publish to HTML it uses a default CSS which doesn't look very nice.

After publishing, I manually jank out the old CSS for a custom one.

Is there a way in Emacs to make it use my other CSS file per default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `:style` parameter in your publishing project.  For example:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("Homepage"
     :base-directory "~/git/homepage/"
     :base-extension "org"
     :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
     :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
     :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" />")))
```

You can also define a per-file option like this:

```
#+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
```

Do <kbd>C-h v org-export-html-style TAB TAB</kbd> to list various options related to the style for HTML export.

Comment: Is it possible to have the CSS embedded (like the emacs default css is also embedded)?

Comment: to answer my own comment:  yes it is possible: just enter <style> ..css styles.. </style>  where now the link to the external style sheet is given