# how to set a global org publish export setting in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode, publishing

As a follow up to this question: [superuser question 431356](https://superuser.com/questions/431356/how-can-i-make-emacs-use-other-css-for-orgmode-publish)

How can I specify org mode publish setting globally? So not per project, but for any .org file I happen to publish?

so instead of:

```
 (setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(("Homepage"
  :base-directory "~/git/homepage/"
  :base-extension "org"
  :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
  :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
  :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" />")))
```

or this for every file:

```
 #+STYLE: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
```

I want something that changes the defaults of any org file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `org-export-html-style` and `org-export-html-style-extra`.

The first has all the default values for org export, so you'd better leave as is unless you want to override everything.

`org-export-html-style-extra` gets appended after the default style definition with your own variations.

I use this setting:

```
"<style type=\"text/css\">\n  html {\n  font-family: sans-serif;\n  font-size: 11pt;\n  }\n  em { font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;}\n</style>"
```

Comment: GREAT! That was the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Juancho's answer worked for me, with one change: when going through the org-mode customization menu (Customize > Export > HTML > Style Extras) I had to remove the \n and escape characters.

Comment: This should really be a comment to the top answer.

Comment: Agreed, but I don't see an "Add comment" by the top answer.

Comment: ah perhaps you don't have enough reputation points to post a comment. (I think you have to have a few hundred points (their way to fight spam))