# How to define template for org-mode HTML export?

Tags: emacs, blogging, org-mode, publishing

I am using org-mode to generate html pages from my notes. I used [Publishing Org-mode files to HTML](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html) to setup blog system.

I have defined an export template. But to use it I have to add following line in top of my every org file inside my notes project.

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org
```

Is there a way to set this up in `.emacs` or to customize an org-mode variable so that I do not have to place this line in every file?

According to [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#In_002dbuffer-settings), `#+SETUPFILE` is an in-buffer setting. Does this mean I cannot define 
it globally for all org files?

[These](https://superuser.com/a/431386/42415) [two](https://superuser.com/a/431518/42415) answers on SU tell how to customize style for HTML export. 
But my template file contains other settings besides CSS style. So only customizing style won't do it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I understand.

If you need to define settings globally, you should define [Options for the HTML/LaTeX exporters](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Publishing-options) in `org-publish-project-alist` inside `.emacs`.

`#+SETUPFILE` is to be used when you need to override global settings and define custom settings for few or a single file. If those settings are used frequently, you can define a template and use SETUPFILE to instruct org-mode to use the template to export this org file.

So I solved my problem by defining global settings in `.emacs` and dropped the idea of using a global template

```
     :author "Andy"
     :email "abc@gmail.com"
     :language "en"
     :link_home "index.html"
     :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"css/style.css\" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [add](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) hook [org-publish-before-export-hook](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-configs/org-hooks.html) with the function like

```
(defun my-add-setup ()
  "Insert SETUPFILE statement in the beginning of the buffer for export ONLY."
  (interactive) ; for testing in scratch
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (insert "#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org\n")
)
```

P.S. I did not try it myself.

Comment: If anyone could update this answer, I would be interested in knowing how to do this. [This hook was apparently dropped from org-mode](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-10/msg00378.html) since this answer was posted.