# Emacs Org-mode: Configuring export behavior

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

In emacs, is it possible to configure an "org" file to have different exporting behaviors depending on the output format?

For example: I'd like to export equations as itself for LaTeX, but as images (I believe it is achieved with the option `tex:imagemagick`) when exporting to HTML.

Comment: Please note that we consider cross-posting to different Stack Exchange sites to be  abusive behavior. So if you cross-posted the same question (I cannot find it on U&L, if you did this), please delete (or flag for deletion) all duplicates.

Comment: @DanielBeck It looks like I was a bit too trigger-happy here. Consider http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94619/2465 Interestingly, the U&L question was closed briefly for that reason (U&L has a specific close reason "posted on multiple sites"), so I wasn't the only one who thought they were very similar. **Dox**, it might be better when you do something like this in the future to *clearly* differentiate the questions from one another, to avoid such mishaps.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Right, thanks for clarifying. I already assumed this based on your comments being deleted. OTOH I wanted to clarify the cross-posting policy in general, given that Dox writes: "*and additionally it's a different group*".

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior you want can somehow be implemented by code added to the heading of the output file, you have various tags to work with like `#+LATEX_HEADER`,  `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS` or `#+HTML_HEAD` (depending on the version of org-mode). Check the general org-mode documentation for more details.

If that's not good enough, and you need to roll your own back-end, see the [Org Export Documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html).

Many other potentially useful suggestions can be found over at these related questions:

- [How to define template for org-mode HTML export?](https://superuser.com/questions/444105/how-to-define-template-for-org-mode-html-export)
- [Customizing org-mode export template?](https://superuser.com/questions/483623/customizing-org-mode-export-template)